# What is the predicted "risk score" generated by sjPlot plot_model?

Tags: survival, data-visualization, cox-model, relative-risk

I ran the following time-varying covariate cox model:

```
model_int <- survival::coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, status) ~  nat + dist + 
                               sex + sf + popDens + medInc + 
                              popDens*nat + popDens*dist + popDens*medInc, 
                             data = model_df)
```

and I get the following summary

```
Call:
survival::coxph(formula = Surv(tstart, tstop, status) ~ nat + 
    dist + sex + sf + popDens + medInc + popDens * nat + popDens * 
    dist + popDens * medInc, data = model_df)

  n= 43846, number of events= 154 
   (251 observations deleted due to missingness)

                    coef exp(coef)  se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
nat            -0.121507  0.885585  0.124637 -0.975 0.329614    
dist           -0.195417  0.822492  0.123732 -1.579 0.114255    
sexm           -0.021949  0.978290  0.168305 -0.130 0.896240    
sftransient     0.659347  1.933530  0.182534  3.612 0.000304 ***
popDens         0.552056  1.736821  0.178899  3.086 0.002030 ** 
medInc          0.006984  1.007008  0.074640  0.094 0.925454    
nat:popDens     0.645145  1.906263  0.199470  3.234 0.001219 ** 
dist:popDens    0.190398  1.209730  0.151516  1.257 0.208894    
popDens:medInc  0.019754  1.019950  0.073993  0.267 0.789491    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I plotted the interaction effect by using plot_model to generate predicted values for 5 quantiles of nat across a range of popDens values (please ignore the title):

```
sjPlot::plot_model(model_int, type = "emm", 
                   terms = c("popDens [-0.369923, 10]", "nat [-1.44193, -1.0567426, 0.0988196,0.9012933, 1.551297]"),
                   title = "Predicted Hazard Ratios",
                   legend.title = "Proportion Natural \nHabitat (quantiles)") + 
  scale_color_discrete(labels = c("0%", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%")) + 
  theme_bw()
```

And I get the following plot:
[image: Interaction plot]

So, how does plot_model generate risk scores? Is it the hazard ratio? If so is it the ratio of hazard rates between the new data and sample data? I haven't found anything definitive in the sjPlot or ggemeans documentation.